# How can I change questions from text fields to radiobuttons?

Tags: javascript, html

the quiz should give +2 marks for right answer and -1 for wrong then display the final mark with the submit button and a clear or reset button.

I need to change the questions from text fields to radiobuttons(if possible with getradiovalue() ).
(I added the earlier one because i thought this was more harder to correct, i am not really sure on how to go ahead with the marks and the radio buttons )

```js
var myVar;

function startTimer() {
    myVar = setInterval(function () {
        myTimer()
    }, 1000);
    timelimit = maxtimelimit;
}

function myTimer() {
    if (timelimit > 0) {
        curmin = Math.floor(timelimit / 60);
        cursec = timelimit % 60;
        if (curmin != 0) {
            curtime = curmin + " minutes and " + cursec + " seconds left";
        } else {
            curtime = cursec + " seconds left";
        }
        $_('timeleft').innerHTML = curtime;
    } else {
        $_('timeleft').innerHTML = timelimit + ' - Out of Time - no credit given for answer ';
        //    clearInterval(myVar);
        checkAnswer();
    }
    timelimit--;
}



var pos = 0,
    posn, choice, correct = 0,
    rscore = 0;
var maxtimelimit = 60,
    timelimit = maxtimelimit;

var questions = [
    ['Chair', 'Table'],
    ['Pen', 'Pencil'],
    ['Box', 'Circle'],
    ['Triangle', 'Rectangle'],
    ['Gun', 'Knife']
];
var questionOrder = [];
var maxNumberOfQuestions = questions.length;
var maxNumberToDisplay = 5;

function setQuestionOrder() {
    questionOrder.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < maxNumberOfQuestions; i++) {
        questionOrder.push(i);
    }
    questionOrder.sort(randOrd);
    pos = 0;
    posn = questionOrder[pos];
}

function $_(IDS) {
    return document.getElementById(IDS);
}

function randOrd() {
    return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5);
}

function renderResults() {
    var test = $_("test");
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + maxNumberToDisplay + " questions correct < /h2>";
    $_("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
    $_('timeleft').innerHTML = '';
    test.innerHTML += '<button onclick="location.reload()">Re-test</a> ';
    setQuestionOrder();
    correct = 0;
    clearInterval(myVar);
    return false;
}

function renderQuestion() {
    var test = $_("test");
    $_("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of "+maxNumberToDisplay;
    if (rscore != 0) {
        $_("test_status").innerHTML += '<br>Currently: ' +
            (correct / rscore * 100).toFixed(0) + '% correct';
    }
    var question = questions[posn][0];
    var chA = questions[posn][1];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='text' id='choices' value=''><p>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";

}

function setupTimer() {
    timelimit = maxtimelimit;
    clearInterval(myVar);
    startTimer();
}

function checkAnswer() {
    var correctChoice = questions[posn][1];
    var userChoice = document.getElementById("choices").value;
    rscore++;
    if (userChoice.toLowerCase() == correctChoice.toLowerCase() && timelimit >
        0) {
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    posn = questionOrder[pos];
    if (pos < maxNumberToDisplay) {
        renderQuestion();
    } else {
        renderResults();
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    setQuestionOrder();
    renderQuestion();
    setupTimer();
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="test_status"> Quiz</h2>
  <h3 id="timeleft">Time left</h3>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: And what's the question? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: need to make it so that each right answer gets 2 marks and wrong get -1 mark. finally the result must be displayed with the correct and wrong answer plus how much  time it took to complete the quiz and the score.

Comment: Uh... well, sounds good :) And what have you tried? Because currently there's no question, no problem and nothing to debug. You're just exposing your project

Comment: yes well tried something else and got stuck so i decided to post the original code i started with.

Comment: i tried another method and i got so far as to get the questions in text box but i dont know how to convert them to radio buttons.

Comment: let me edit the question so it differnt

Comment: OK so I ran your code and it seems to work pretty well so far... no error, nothing stuck... I still don't get where the problem is?

Comment: You can refer to this link https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-javascript-quiz/